# Difference between classToTableName & tableName & collectionTableName in Hibernate NamingStrategy?

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate annotations and I want to change class(table) names to "t_xx".
but I do not know to use which of them(classToTableName & tableName & collectionTableName).

Comment: @Table(name = "t_xx") annotation over your class definition should work.

Comment: I have a few tables and I do not want to change them one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a custom Naming Strategy by extending [DefaultNamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html) class.

Here is the explanation on these methods:

- `classToTableName(java.lang.String)` : When you have declared a class using `@Entity` and without any `@Table(name="...") then this method will be called to get the name of the DB table from your class name.
- `collectionTableName(...)` : When a join table is needed then this method will be called by hibernate.
- `tableName(java.lang.String)` : When you have declared an entity along with `@Table(name="table_name"), then hibernate calls this method by passing the value of name attribute to this method.

If you have not declared any naming strategy then hibernate uses [DefaultNamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/DefaultNamingStrategy.html)

So extend this class and override the method like this:

```
public String  classToTableName(String className) {
   return "t_"+super.classToTableName(className);
}


public String collectionTableName(String ownerEntity, String ownerEntityTable, String associatedEntity, String associatedEntityTable,String propertyName) {
   return "t_"+super.collectionTableName(ownerEntity,ownerEntityTable,associatedEntity,associatedEntityTable,propertyName);
}
```

If needed you can override the `tableName(String)` if you want to change the value of the attribute for `name` in `@Table` annotation.